# Convert bootstrap grid div to table tr td

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to convert to `div row and col` to `table tr td` format using PHP or JQuery?

I've been doing some googling but all the result are the opposite. Table to Div.

I can't imagine doing this with a simple str_replace since you can't really know the ending div for a row or a col. So I was hoping you can guide me to the right path for this.

HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" data-type="container-content">
            <section data-type="component-text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro labore architecto fuga tempore omnis aliquid, rerum numquam deleniti ipsam earum velit aliquam deserunt, molestiae o<span style="color:#00FFFF;">fficiis mollitia accusantium suscipit fugiat esse magnam eaque cumque, iste corrupti magni? Illo dicta saepe, maiores fugit aliquid consequuntur aut, rem ex iusto dolorem molestias obcaecati eveniet vel voluptatibus recusandae illum, voluptatem! Odit est possimus nesciunt.</span></p>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" data-type="container-content">
            <section data-type="component-text"><h2><span style="color:#FF8C00;"><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro labore architecto fuga tempore omnis aliquid, rerum numquam deleniti ipsam earum velit aliquam deserunt, molestiae officiis mollitia accusantium suscipit fugiat esse magnam eaque cumque, iste corrupti magni? Illo dicta saepe, maiores fugit aliquid consequuntur aut, rem ex iusto dolorem molestias obcaecati eveniet vel voluptatibus recusandae illum, voluptatem! Odit est possimus nesciunt.</strong></span></span></h2>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" data-type="container-content">
                <section data-type="component-text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro labore architecto fuga tempore omnis aliquid, rerum numquam deleniti ipsam earum velit aliquam deserunt, molestiae o<span style="color:#00FFFF;">fficiis mollitia accusantium suscipit fugiat esse magnam eaque cumque, iste corrupti magni? Illo dicta saepe, maiores fugit aliquid consequuntur aut, rem ex iusto dolorem molestias obcaecati eveniet vel voluptatibus recusandae illum, voluptatem! Odit est possimus nesciunt.</span></p>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" data-type="container-content">
                <section data-type="component-text"><h2><span style="color:#FF8C00;"><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro labore architecto fuga tempore omnis aliquid, rerum numquam deleniti ipsam earum velit aliquam deserunt, molestiae officiis mollitia accusantium suscipit fugiat esse magnam eaque cumque, iste corrupti magni? Illo dicta saepe, maiores fugit aliquid consequuntur aut, rem ex iusto dolorem molestias obcaecati eveniet vel voluptatibus recusandae illum, voluptatem! Odit est possimus nesciunt.</strong></span></span></h2>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

To table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <section data-type="component-text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro labore architecto fuga tempore omnis aliquid, rerum numquam deleniti ipsam earum velit aliquam deserunt, molestiae o<span style="color:#00FFFF;">fficiis mollitia accusantium suscipit fugiat esse magnam eaque cumque, iste corrupti magni? Illo dicta saepe, maiores fugit aliquid consequuntur aut, rem ex iusto dolorem molestias obcaecati eveniet vel voluptatibus recusandae illum, voluptatem! Odit est possimus nesciunt.</span></p>
            </section>
        </td>
        <td>
            <section data-type="component-text"><h2><span style="color:#FF8C00;"><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro labore architecto fuga tempore omnis aliquid, rerum numquam deleniti ipsam earum velit aliquam deserunt, molestiae officiis mollitia accusantium suscipit fugiat esse magnam eaque cumque, iste corrupti magni? Illo dicta saepe, maiores fugit aliquid consequuntur aut, rem ex iusto dolorem molestias obcaecati eveniet vel voluptatibus recusandae illum, voluptatem! Odit est possimus nesciunt.</strong></span></span></h2>
            </section>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <section data-type="component-text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro labore architecto fuga tempore omnis aliquid, rerum numquam deleniti ipsam earum velit aliquam deserunt, molestiae o<span style="color:#00FFFF;">fficiis mollitia accusantium suscipit fugiat esse magnam eaque cumque, iste corrupti magni? Illo dicta saepe, maiores fugit aliquid consequuntur aut, rem ex iusto dolorem molestias obcaecati eveniet vel voluptatibus recusandae illum, voluptatem! Odit est possimus nesciunt.</span></p>
            </section>
        </td>
        <td>
            <section data-type="component-text"><h2><span style="color:#FF8C00;"><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro labore architecto fuga tempore omnis aliquid, rerum numquam deleniti ipsam earum velit aliquam deserunt, molestiae officiis mollitia accusantium suscipit fugiat esse magnam eaque cumque, iste corrupti magni? Illo dicta saepe, maiores fugit aliquid consequuntur aut, rem ex iusto dolorem molestias obcaecati eveniet vel voluptatibus recusandae illum, voluptatem! Odit est possimus nesciunt.</strong></span></span></h2>
            </section>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you

Comment: why not just do it using css?  `display:table` etc.  It would be useful, if you showed your starting html and showed us what you want to convert it to

Comment: I did not know that. let me post my HTML then. Also, to the one that wants to close this question is about programming. What else would you call converting div to table as?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using css only - by changing the [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) type to `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell`:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table > .row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table > .row > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<section class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" data-type="container-content">
      <section data-type="component-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro labore architecto fuga tempore omnis aliquid, rerum numquam deleniti ipsam earum velit aliquam deserunt, molestiae o<span style="color:#00FFFF;">fficiis mollitia accusantium suscipit fugiat esse magnam eaque cumque, iste corrupti magni? Illo dicta saepe, maiores fugit aliquid consequuntur aut, rem ex iusto dolorem molestias obcaecati eveniet vel voluptatibus recusandae illum, voluptatem! Odit est possimus nesciunt.</span></p>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" data-type="container-content">
      <section data-type="component-text">
        <h2><span style="color:#FF8C00;"><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro labore architecto fuga tempore omnis aliquid, rerum numquam deleniti ipsam earum velit aliquam deserunt, molestiae officiis mollitia accusantium suscipit fugiat esse magnam eaque cumque, iste corrupti magni? Illo dicta saepe, maiores fugit aliquid consequuntur aut, rem ex iusto dolorem molestias obcaecati eveniet vel voluptatibus recusandae illum, voluptatem! Odit est possimus nesciunt.</strong></span></span></h2>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" data-type="container-content">
      <section data-type="component-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro labore architecto fuga tempore omnis aliquid, rerum numquam deleniti ipsam earum velit aliquam deserunt, molestiae o<span style="color:#00FFFF;">fficiis mollitia accusantium suscipit fugiat esse magnam eaque cumque, iste corrupti magni? Illo dicta saepe, maiores fugit aliquid consequuntur aut, rem ex iusto dolorem molestias obcaecati eveniet vel voluptatibus recusandae illum, voluptatem! Odit est possimus nesciunt.</span></p>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" data-type="container-content">
      <section data-type="component-text">
        <h2><span style="color:#FF8C00;"><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive;"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro labore architecto fuga tempore omnis aliquid, rerum numquam deleniti ipsam earum velit aliquam deserunt, molestiae officiis mollitia accusantium suscipit fugiat esse magnam eaque cumque, iste corrupti magni? Illo dicta saepe, maiores fugit aliquid consequuntur aut, rem ex iusto dolorem molestias obcaecati eveniet vel voluptatibus recusandae illum, voluptatem! Odit est possimus nesciunt.</strong></span></span></h2>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

In the above example, I have added a class of table on your top level sections just so they can be distinguished against the other sections.

It also keeps your html structure semantically correct (as it does not look like the data is tabular - therefore you shouldn't use table tags)

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this out